# segmentation fault recvfrom assembly

Tags: sockets, assembly, nasm

I am getting a segmentation fault for the following assembly code which get messages in socket

```
global _start

struc sockaddr_in
    .sin_family resw 1
    .sin_port resw 1
    .sin_addr resd 1
    .sin_zero resb 8
endstruc

struc img
    .source_ip  resb 4
    .int_ip resb 4
    .group_ip   resb 4
endstruc

section .bss

    listen_socket:  resq 1
    buffer: resb 2048

section .data

pop_sa istruc sockaddr_in
        at sockaddr_in.sin_family, dw 2           ; AF_INET
        at sockaddr_in.sin_port, dw 0x4b9c        ; port 40011
        at sockaddr_in.sin_addr, dd 0xb46c0ef             ; INADDR_ANY
        at sockaddr_in.sin_zero, dd 0, 0
iend
sockaddr_in_len     equ $ - pop_sa

pop_mc  istruc img  ;
    at img.source_ip,   dd 0xb46c0ef ;
    at img.int_ip,      dd 0             ; INADDR_ANY
    at img.group_ip,    dd 0x5a81320a ;
iend
img_len equ $ - pop_mc
from_ip:    dw 0    
from_ip_len:    db 16

section .text

_start:

    mov rdi, 2      ;AF_INET
    mov rsi, 2      ;SOCK_DGRAM
    mov rdx, 0      ;IPPROTO_UDP
    mov rax, 41
    syscall         ;sys_create_udp_socket
    mov[listen_socket], rax

    mov r8, 4        
    mov r10, 1   
    mov rdx, 2  ;SO_REUSEADDR
    mov rsi, 1  ;SOL_SOCKET
    mov rdi,[listen_socket]
    mov rax, 54
    syscall         ;sys_setsockopt

    mov rdx, sockaddr_in_len
    mov rsi, pop_sa
    mov rdi,[listen_socket]
    mov rax, 49
    syscall         ;sys_bind

    mov r8, img_len
    mov r10, pop_mc
    mov rdx, 39     ;IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP
    mov rsi, 0  ;IPPROTO_UDP
    mov rdi,[listen_socket]
    mov rax, 54
    syscall         ;sys_setsockopt

    mov r9, [from_ip_len]   ;
    mov r8, [from_ip]
    mov r10, 0
    mov rdx, 2047
    mov rsi, buffer
    mov rdi,[listen_socket]
    mov rax, 45
    syscall         ;sys_recvfrom

    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60
    syscall         ;sys_exit
```

All syscalls return right value before sys_recvfrom, where I get error - EFAULT in sys_recvfrom function, what wrong? 64 bit assembly nasm.

Answer (score 0):

r8 and r9 (sockaddr and socklen) are expected to be of type pointer. You move the value from an address from a dw variable into a register, do you mean to use lea for r8 ? And even then, passing a pointer to a two byte variable, that you say is 16-bytes large (socklen)

My assembler, and my unix related assembler in particular is rusty, but my guess would be

1. you think dw is 16 byte while it is 16 bit.
2. you load the values into r8,r9 with mov reg,[variable] instead of the address using lea reg, [variable]

Comment: Thanks Marco van de Voort

Comment: In that case I get in rax register length of message, it's ok, but in buffer no data.